# Get array text filed value via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

in my process text filed in array i need to get the value via javascript but my code is not working my code following

```
<input type="text" id="itemid[]" name="itemid[]" class="span12"/>
```

and javascript code is

```
function getstock()
{
 var itemidarr=document.getElementById('itemid[]');
 if(itemidarr!= null)
 {

    alert(itemidarr.length);

 }
}
```

any other solution for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript get input text value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Comment: HTML Ids can't contain brackets (`[]`).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: I don't know what you intended with `itemidarr.length`, but DOM elements don't have a `length` property.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: Yes they can: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id.

Comment: Felix Kling:any other solution for this progress

Comment: @FelixKling it looks like that's the problem though.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: I doubt it: http://jsfiddle.net/352bZ/

Comment: *"any other solution for this progress"* You haven't even explained what the problem is. *What* exactly does not work? What do you expect the code to do and what does it do? You said "it doesn't work", but we don't even know what you expect it do to. If you expect the code to brew coffee, well, them it's obvious that "it doesn't work".

Comment: @FelixKling k, you win. I thought it could be an old DOCTYPE issue, but i'm guessing modern browsers know how to overcome it.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: Yeah, I think there never was really a problem with that (maybe in really old browsers).

Comment: @FelixKling I'm used to rails automatically changing `item[x]` names to `item_x` ids

Comment: The only advice I can give you is to [learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and poke around the code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id attribute here cannot contain [  ].

Put your textboxex in "fieldset tag"
Like:

```
<fieldset id="field">
//Put you text boxes here<input type='text'>
</fieldset>
```

Access these by:

```
document.getElementById("list....").getElementsByTagName("input")[indexoftext];
```

indexoftext is the text box you wan to choose.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes they can: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id.

Answer (score 1):

The IDs can't contain brackets, these: [], so:

```
<input type="text" id="itemid1" name="itemname1" class="span12"/>
<input type="text" id="itemid2" name="itemname1" class="span12"/>
<input type="text" id="itemid3" name="itemname1" class="span12"/>
```

Then you have to loop through the IDs:

```
function getstock()
{
     for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
         var itemidarr=document.getElementById("itemid"+i);
         if(itemidarr!= null) alert(itemidarr.length);   
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes they can: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. Guess they can.

Comment: Also (this is something you might not know when you are not working with PHP), the `[]` in the fields names are important. It lets PHP know to treat multiple elements with the same name as an array. It's strange, but that's the way it is :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an array to fill in an input text, only for input like radio or checkbox.

Text input only accept a single string.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like  this below

```
<input type="text" id="itemid" name="itemid" class="span12"/>
function getstock()
{
    var itemidarr = document.getElementsByName('itemid');
        for(var i = 0; i < itemidarr.length; i++){
            var item=document.getElementsByName('itemid')[i].value;
                if(item!= null)
                {
                  alert(item);
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this?

Comment: OP should try this as the first line should get and array of itemid. then loop them all grabbing the value of each one and alerting it

Comment: You should explain this in your answer. Also, why did you remove the `[]`? They are essential for processing the fields in PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: sorry very new to this :(  trying to be help full. only removed the [] for this but yes they are needed for php

Comment: @hen Raj sorry i missed of some "s"

Answer (score 0):

> function getstock() {
>
> var a = [];
>       jQuery.each(this, function(i, field){
>           a.push($.trim(field.value));
>       });
>       return a;
>
> }

can u use this code

Comment: i had change my code what u mention like that but i didn't get

Comment: or try this $('input[name="itemid[]"]').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});

Answer (score 0):

i got the result

```
function getstock1()
    {
    alert("test");
        var itemidarr = document.getElementsByName('itemid[]');
        for (var i = 0; i < itemidarr.length; i++)
        {
            alert(itemidarr[i].value);
        }
```

Comment: If this is an answer, you can accept your own answer. Or if it is a part of your question, you can simply edit your question.